# How to determine where a multivariable function isn't differentiable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

consider $f(x,y) = \max(x+2y, x^2+y^2)$, how do i find the points at which this isn't differentiable.

I've tried taking the partial derivative of $x$ and $y$, for general points, but i get stuck with an equation that i can't seem to simplify, is this the wrong method?

Comment: I see that it is the 18th time you post here. Please do use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How can a function depend on two variables but only contain one in its argument? I think you mean $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Basically what you have is a function that changes its behaviour along one or more curves (the curve where$ x+2y = x^2 + y^2$, maybe excluding the origin). Find a parametrization for such a curve and tey to find whether the function is differentiable there. My bet is that approaching this curve from the$ x+2y $part and the $x^2 + y^2$ part will yield different results. Maybe it will be differentiable at some points, but not differentiable in most of those points

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

The attached plot shows $f(x,y)$

[image]

Considering the change of coordinates

$$
\{x,y,z\}\Leftrightarrow\{r \sin (\phi ) \cos (\theta ),r \sin (\phi ) \sin (\theta ),r \cos (\phi )\}
$$

in the equations

$$
x^2+y^2 = z\\
x + 2y = z
$$

we get the parameterization for the intersection curve as

$$
\left\{\cos (\theta ) (2 \sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta )),\sin (\theta ) (2 \sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta )),(2 \sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta ))^2\right\}
$$

for $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ shown in blue.

Answer (score 0):

To get the function differentiable at the intersection of both surfaces, you need that the derivatives are the same, $(1,2)=(2x,2y)$. This is only the case for the point $(x,y)=(\frac12,1)$. Now $x+2y=\frac94$ and $x^2+y^2=\frac54$, so that this is inside the intersection circle where the first function is dominant, not on its boundary.